# Ordered list rendered as flexbox doesn't show bullets/decimals (items also rendered as flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an ordered list (`ol`) that has it's `display` property set to `flex`. Also the list items are rendered as flexboxes. Doing this results in the bullets (numbers) not being shown anymore.

**Is there any way I can get the bullets to show on the `ol` with classes `.questions.questions--likert` (in the area where the 40px `padding` is)?**

See **Fiddle** (contains SCSS): http://jsfiddle.net/3y5t0xpx/3/

*HTML & compiled CSS below:*

HTML

```
<form class="form  form--test" name="frm-identification" action="/" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <h2>Identificatie</h2>
        <p>Gelieve volgende gegevens in te vullen vooraleer de test te starten.</p>
        <ol class="questions  questions--likert">
            <li class="question">
                <p class="description">Inventieve ideeen brengen</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><label class="input-container  input-container--radio"><input type="radio" name="rbt-t1q1" id="rbt-t1q1-1" value="1" /><span class="value">1</span></label></li>
                    <li><label class="input-container  input-container--radio"><input type="radio" name="rbt-t1q1" id="rbt-t1q1-2" value="2" /><span class="value">2</span></label></li>
                    <li><label class="input-container  input-container--radio"><input type="radio" name="rbt-t1q1" id="rbt-t1q1-3" value="3" /><span class="value">3</span></label></li>
                    <li><label class="input-container  input-container--radio"><input type="radio" name="rbt-t1q1" id="rbt-t1q1-4" value="4" /><span class="value">4</span></label></li>
                    <li><label class="input-container  input-container--radio"><input type="radio" name="rbt-t1q1" id="rbt-t1q1-5" value="5" /><span class="value">5</span></label></li>
                    <li><label class="input-container  input-container--radio"><input type="radio" name="rbt-t1q1" id="rbt-t1q1-6" value="6" /><span class="value">6</span></label></li>
                    <li><label class="input-container  input-container--radio"><input type="radio" name="rbt-t1q1" id="rbt-t1q1-7" value="7" /><span class="value">7</span></label></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Compiled CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,600italic);
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  color: #333;
  font: 87.5% 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

ul, ol {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul li, ol li {
  margin: 0 0 0 1.5rem;
  padding: 0;
}

ol {
  list-style: decimal outside none;
}

ul {
  list-style: disc outside none;
}

.form input, .form textarea {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}

.form dl {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.form dl dt, .form dl dd {
  padding: 0 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.form dl dt {
  font-size: 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.form dl dt .required {
  color: #f00;
}

.form ol {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.form ol li {
  margin: 0;
}

.form fieldset {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.questions {
  list-style: decimal outside none;
}

.questions li {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.questions.questions--likert .question {
  display: flex;
}

.questions.questions--likert .question .description {
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}

.questions.questions--likert .question ul {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 420px;
  list-style: none outside none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.questions.questions--likert .question ul li {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.questions.questions--likert .question ul li .input-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.input-container.input-container--radio {
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.input-container.input-container--radio:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.input-container.input-container--radio:hover .value {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-container.input-container--radio .value {
  background: #bfbdbc;
  clear: both;
  color: #28211e;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.857143rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

Comment: you could use a `counter` and the `before` psuedo selector: http://jsfiddle.net/3y5t0xpx/1/

Comment: That's one option indeed, not the best, but viable if no better solution is available.

Comment: Not all CSS code in your fiddle has been compiled. Check classes `.questions` and `.input-container`. Don't expect an answer from non-SASS/LESS coders anytime soon (like me). Glad to help when you modified the fiddle...

Comment: Hey @RenevanderLende, I just switched out the SCSS from the Fiddle, and added in the compiled CSS instead.

Comment: @Gerrit Bertier cool, thanks for taht. I already created a plain html version myself too. Having a look at it now. In the mean time add `* * { outline: 1px dashed red }` (two *'s) as last line to your CSS, this will give you more insight finding the error.

Comment: I just removed the last space in `.input-container.input-container--radio .value`, now I see numbers. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Hi @RenevanderLende, nope. I want the numbers of the `ol` element to show. So a "1" should be rendered next to the left of "Inventieve ideeen brengen"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95584/discussion-between-rene-van-der-lende-and-gerrit-bertier).

Comment: `list-style` applies to elements with `display: list-item` only – so by making your LI `display: flex`, you are removing the prerequisite for `list-style` to have any effect. Using a `counter` is probably your best bet here.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`list-style` applies to elements with `display: list-item` only – so by making your LI `display: flex`, you are removing the prerequisite for `list-style` to have any effect.

Using a `counter` is probably your best bet here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into the same problem. After reading this topic, I thought that there is no simple solution, but I still found it.
You can simply add a container inside the list and give all the necessary styles to the container and not to the list.

```
 <li>
    <div class="question">
        ------
    </div>
</li>
```