# Why does flexbox affect its containing list-item's marker?

Tags: css, flexbox, listitem

After knowing that [a `list-item` element cannot be `display: flex` at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805682/#answers), I wrap my contents with a container, then put the container inside the `<li />`.

Things go right for elements with content.
However, if the first element in the container has no child nodes, the marker of the `<li />` is unexpectedly located at the bottom.

Though in my case I can simply add a `display: none` to workaround, I'm still confused:
**How can the content in the flexbox affect its grandparent node?**

Example: (the marker `1.` is located at the bottom right of the `<li />`)

```css
.flex { display: flex; }
```

```html
<ol style="width: 15em">
    <li>
        <div class="flex">
            <div></div>
          <div>When an element without content is preceding, the ::marker of the list-item is located at the bottom.</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="flex">
            <div>TITLE</div>
            <div>If there's content in the first element, then it goes as expected.</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="flex">
            <div>It's also fine if there's only one child here.</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Relating question:
CSS pseudo-element `::marker` is not implemented in popular browsers, and only Firefox supports [@counter-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style). For now what is recommended to implement user-defined markers in `<ol />`? (I've seen some people using `::before` to do that, in order to make user NOT to copy the text of the marker. But I don't know if it's good or not.)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40413013/3597276

Comment: You'll get a lot more control if you remove the native HTML list styling `list-style: none` and add your own back with a pseudo-element and a css counter

Comment: Using ::before is an awful hack with all sorts of pitfalls that come with trying to pretend something is a marker when it's not, but it's all that we've had for many years and will continue to be stuck with for as long as ::marker remains unimplemented. In other words, "it's as good as it's going to get".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the issue simply adjust the alignment to be baseline: <sup>*(another solution at the end)*</sup>

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items:baseline;
}
```

```html
<ol style="width: 15em">
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div></div>
      <div>When an element without content is preceding, the ::marker of the list-item is located at the bottom.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div>TITLE</div>
      <div>If there's content in the first element, then it goes as expected.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div>It's also fine if there's only one child here.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

---

To better understand what is happening (based on my own interpretation) let's add some width and background to the empty element:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
div:empty {
  width:30px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<ol style="width: 15em">
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div></div>
      <div>When an element without content is preceding, the ::marker of the list-item is located at the bottom.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div>TITLE</div>
      <div>If there's content in the first element, then it goes as expected.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div>It's also fine if there's only one child here.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

The empty element is stretched because of the default alignment and then the numerotation is aligned with its bottom.

If you increase/decrease the height you will better notice this

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
div:empty {
  width:30px;
  background:red;
  animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes change {
   from {
     height:5px;
   }
   to  {
     height:80px;
   }
}
```

```html
<ol style="width: 15em">
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div></div>
      <div>When an element without content is preceding, the ::marker of the list-item is located at the bottom.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div>TITLE</div>
      <div>If there's content in the first element, then it goes as expected.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div>It's also fine if there's only one child here.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

This will also happen if you have for example an `inline-block` element inside the first flex item set to `overlow:hidden` (making its baseline the bottom border)

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
div:empty {
  width:30px;
  background:red;
}
.inline-block {
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
  background:green;
  width:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<ol style="width: 15em">
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div></div>
      <div>When an element without content is preceding, the ::marker of the list-item is located at the bottom.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div><div class="inline-block">some text </div></div>
      <div>TITLE</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div>It's also fine if there's only one child here.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Basically the numerotation is trying to get aligned with the baseline of the first item. If you increase the `font-size` of the first item we can also notice this:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.size {
  animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes change {
   from {
     font-size:5px;
   }
   to  {
     font-size:30px;
   }
}
```

```html
<ol style="width: 15em">
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div></div>
      <div>When an element without content is preceding, the ::marker of the list-item is located at the bottom.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="size">TITLE</div>
      <div>If there's content in the first element, then it goes as expected.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div>It's also fine if there's only one child here.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

---

As you already noticed this only happen if it's about the first item which make this a bit complex and not easy to explain:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
div:empty {
  width:30px;
  background:red;
}
.inline-block {
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
  background:green;
  width:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<ol style="width: 15em">
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div>When an element without content is preceding, the ::marker of the list-item is located at the bottom.</div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div>TITLE</div>
      <div><div class="inline-block">some text </div></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div>It's also fine if there's only one child here.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Another workaround in addition to changing the alignment is to consider a pseudo element inside the flexbox container that will be our first flex item thus we avoid any interaction with our *real* elements.

The trick is to not keep that element empty but with at least a content. I have used a the zero width space character `\200B`:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex:before {
  content:"\200B"; /*a non collapsible white space*/ 
}
div:empty {
  width:30px;
  background:red;
  animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes change {
   from {
     height:5px;
   }
   to  {
     height:80px;
   }
}
.size {
  color:green;
  animation:size 5s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes size {
   from {
     font-size:5px;
   }
   to  {
     font-size:20px;
   }
}
```

```html
<ol style="width: 15em">
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div></div>
      <div>When an element without content is preceding, the ::marker of the list-item is located at the bottom.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="size">TITLE</div>
      <div>If there's content in the first element, then it goes as expected.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flex">
      <div>It's also fine if there's only one child here.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with flexbox inside the element but an empty element inside a display flex collapses down so it impacts things oddly. You fix that by giving the elements a "size" using `flex: number` or `flex-basis: 50px`

I would avoid the `::marker` attribute since it's got [horrific support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-marker-pseudo) and simply create your own with a css counter.

Here's an example:

```css
ol {
  display:block;
  width: 30em;
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: counterName;
}
li {
 padding-left: 2em;
 padding-bottom: 1em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
 position: relative;
 counter-increment: counterName;
}
li:before {
  content:'#' counter(counterName);
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}

.flex {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap:no-wrap;
}

.flex > * {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        <div class="flex">
            <div></div>
          <div>When an element without content is preceding, the ::marker of the list-item is located at the bottom.</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="flex">
            <div>TITLE</div>
            <div>If there's content in the first element, then it goes as expected.</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="flex">
            <div>It's also fine if there's only one child here.</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```